# Removing item bound to incrementalloadinglist in ListView

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have a Windows8 xaml listview where I am using the IncrementalLoadingListBase code provided in the Win8 sample to create an infinitly scrolling list that pulls in more content.

When a certain item fails to load (it is dependent on a network request), I'd like to remove the item entirely. Currently I tried to just collapse the item, but then the list looks awkward since the item still has the standard listview padding.

How can I remove the item? IncrementalLoadingListBase does not implement remove, so I tried to "fix" it by adding `this._storage.Remove(value);` . This resulted in the UI not being updated, so then I tried to also add `NotifyOfRemovedItem(value);` , but this would re-render everything and make the app twitch some.

Does anyone have a recommendation on the proper way to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, this is maybe stupid. Is it possible to add each item only after it's fully loaded and validated? This way you wouldn't need to cosider removing "bad" items.

Comment: Sadly, it's not possible JustAndrei - it's for an adcontrol which has to be visible so it can render or tell me no ad was found to display